# Erro ao definir um background em uma label e colocar uma imagem acima do background desta mesma label

Tags: html, css3, css-hover, css-font-face

//html

```
 <label class="home-header icon-menu">
                <img src="arquivos/menu.svg">
            </label>
```

//css

```
.icon-menu {
    position: relative;
    top: 0.5cm;
    left: 0.39cm;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Cara mas isso não é um background, é uma imagem dentro de uma label. Explica melhor o que está tentando fazer, se possível edita sua resposta e coloca tb uma imagem do layout que pretende fazer

Comment: Certo tem a imagem dentro da label. Então, eu gostaria de colocar um fundo na imagem. Por exemplo : Tem a label depois o background e por fim a imagem sob o background.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Obrigado a todos que procuraram me ajudar nas respostas, eu fiz a pergunta da forma errada, agora editei para ficar mais claro. Com explicação do @hugocsl, fui testando no meu código e percebi que estava faltando colocar o display: inline block. Muito obrigado a todos. Me desculpem!

Answer (score 0):

Olha, A forma que você está utilizando a imagem está errada. Para um Background, você vai precisar definir no css que aquela imagem é um background(sem necessidade de chama-la no html), também será necessário definir o comportamento da imagem dentro do container, segue código de exemplo.

ps: Se as classes estiverem sendo usadas por outras tags que você não quer aplicar o background, convem criar uma classe adicional ou ID para o objeto em questão.

html:

```
 <label id="backimg" class="home-header icon-menu"/>
```

css:

```
#backimg {
position: relative;
top: 0.5cm;
left: 0.39cm;
cursor: pointer;
width: 50px; <!-- especificar um tamanho para a tag é importante -->
height: 150px;
background: url('c:/caminho da imagem') no-repeat;
}
```